# javascript - reverse() array is not working

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to use `reverse()` method to reverse a simple array. 
The array is returned from `https` and I need to reverse the element in it.

```
console.log("Before Reverse:")
console.log(this.newArr);
this.newArr[0].reverse();
console.log("After Reverse:")
console.log(this.newArr);
```

[image]

However when I declare an array and use `reverse()` It can be reversed.:

```
var arr = [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6]];
arr.reverse();
```

Please help, thanks!

Comment: I believe you need to assign the reversed array to a new variable.. ex: var reversedArray = this.newArr[0].reverse(); then console.log(reversedArray); see what you get

Comment: @GlenK Thanks! It works by assigning to another variable. Just not sure why is it ?

Comment: Are you using the reverse native method? Maybe make the reverse method async in the class with async/await or promises.

Comment: Array#reverse *transposes the elements of the calling array object **in place***, so assigning to a different variable makes absolutely no difference - the person who suggested that, and the two people that clicked "this comment adds something useful to the post" clearly have no knowledge of javascript - it comes down to what you see in the console - which is explained in the duplicate

Comment: @Michael - what?

Comment: try changing the two `console.log(this.newArr);` to `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.newArr, null, 4));` - now the console won't trick you

Comment: @Bravo by changing the `console.log()` after `reverse()` still doesn't seems to reverse the array

Comment: have you changed **BOTH** console.log so you can see that it has reversed?

Comment: what you are actually seeing is the REVERSED version both times in the console